# Read 24bit files using scipy.io

Tags: scipy, wav, librosa

I have an audio file that is 24bit depth. When I try to read the file using `wavfile`, I get this error:

[image]

I then went ahead and replaced the original wavfile.py by the updated enhanced [wavfile.py found here](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476), that can supposedly read 24bit files.  However, I then got this error:

[image]

For a little extra background, I used Adobe Audition to get the original 24bit file.  But Adobe seems to add extra data like probably meta data to the audio file?  I then used `sox` to write over the Adobe file to an equivalent `sox` 24bit file as I think that `sox` removes this extra meta data?

I also used a 24bit file from the Urbansound dataset and there are no errors.

Can you tell me what I can do to read my 24bit file?

Here is the location of the file I am trying to read:

https://gofile.io/d/2wY2q4

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the file `2IN_HomeStairs_Yeti_4GAL_repop_TCL_b_clp_24bit.wav`?

Comment: @Bob, yes, that is the file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can load the file `2IN_HomeStairs_Yeti_4GAL_repop_TCL_b_clp_24bit.wav` here using

```py
from scipy.io import wavfile
wavfile.read('./Downloads/2IN_HomeStairs_Yeti_4GAL_repop_TCL_b_clp_24bit.wav')
```

I suppose you are using a scipy version earlier than `1.6.0`, when [arbitrary bit depth support was added](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.6.0.html?highlight=arbitrary%20bit%20depth#scipy-io-improvements) (I used 1.6.2 for the above test).